# is there a way to get the unix date and print out all the times of the day corresponding to that day?

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

In my executable file (tsk_gettimes), it prints out a unix timestamp with every piece of information it prints out in the terminal. I was wondering if there was a way that i could have the user input a date (2004,09,19) and it outputs all the unix timestamps that happened on that day (in other words, i send off the date above into the unix converter using zero hours, mins, secs, etc. and it prints out all the times of that day) please let me know if i need to word this better!

i have updated the code to using a range but i am receiving no output.

```
from asyncio import subprocess
import datetime
import time
import subprocess, os

#print("[file name] [year, month, day]")
#filename, keydate = input().split(' ') 
def UNIX(date):

    #takes in input
    x = date

    #prints input date as normal
    print("[date]", x)
    
    #creates unix timestamp after conversion
    keyunix = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple()))
    
    #prints unix timestamp
    print("[UNIXTimestamp]", keyunix)
    return keyunix
 
    

# user file input
print("Enter file name with extention")
filename = input()

#print file name 
print("[file name]", filename )


assert os.path.exists(filename)
assert os.path.exists("C:\\Program Files\\sleuthkit-4.11.1-win32\\bin\\tsk_gettimes.exe")

# user date input
print("Enter date [dd/mm/yyyy]")
userdate = input()

keydate = str(UNIX(userdate))

#86400 seconds in a day
interval = str(int(keydate) + int('86400'))
print("[interval]", 
interval)


#reading the output of the executable fileclear

test = subprocess.run(["C:\\Program Files\\sleuthkit-4.11.1-win32\\bin\\tsk_gettimes.exe", filename],
   stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

output = test.stdout.decode().split('\n')

#retreiving all the matches of the keydate (i)
for i in output:

    #looking for the keydate in the i
    if keydate in i:

        #looking if its in range
        if keydate in range(keydate,interval):
            print(i)
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine the **range** of timestamps for a calendar day?

Comment: No. so my executable file takes in a file that holds computer activity content and prints out all the times the computer is used along with its info. I want to be able to insert a date in the terminal and have it print out all the times of that day it was used.

Comment: So you want to filter a set of times for those that happened on that day (and possibly express them as a time of day)?

Comment: something like that, yes. It has to have user input though. I found that the from one day to the next it is 86400 more.

Comment: Well, yes: that’s the number of seconds in a day!

Comment: yeah, but how do i get just that tio print out

Answer (score 1):

```
def UNIX(date):

    #takes in input
    x = date

    #prints input date as normal
    print("[date]", x)
    
    #creates unix timestamp after conversion
    keyunix = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple()))
    
    #prints unix timestamp
    print("[UNIXTimestamp]", keyunix)
    return keyunix

#looking if its in range
for keydate in str(range(keydate, interval)):

    #retreiving all the matches of the keydate (i)
    for i in output:

        #looking for the keydate in the i
        if keydate in i:
            print(i)
```

this printed out the input i needed from the executable.